# Html special characters not being shown in browser despite UTF-8 meta tag applied to html file

Tags: html, meta-tags, htmlspecialchars

I am using jquery method to load html file in a div content as like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(function () {
    $("#divWelcomePage").load("welcome.html");
});
```

Now, The issue is I got the html file content over there but am not getting the value of special characters like (apostrophe('),double quotes("") in the div.

Then I put a  tag like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

and Now,it works for some html pages but for some other pages I still don't get any value. Instead I get � character:(

Please suggest some really reliable way for me to do so. I have also studied that using html editor to convert these html files to support UTF characters can make this html file work But still it is not working as I have tried to use a few html editor like **Sublime Text 2**.
Please suggest me some good html editor too if you still believe using those editors will help my case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a [valid doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) for html entities to display correctly.

Try adding this to your welcome.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```